# Expose Talend ETL Job as a Web Service

Tags: etl, talend, data-integration

I am currently evaluating Talend ETL (Talend Open Studio for Data Integration).

I would like to know how / if i can expose an ETL Job as a Web Service.

I know i can export jobs as web services and invoke them through a specific URL however, my goal is to be able to expose a specific WSDL with IN / OUT parameters.

A sample use case would be:

1) Invoke WS in Talend ETL and pass XML with data

2) Talend ETL extracts the data from the XML and inserts them as variable(s) in the query to be executed against the DB.

3) Talend ETL tranforms resultset from DB to XML data and responds back to the WS client.

Finally, i would also like to know whether the same scenario can be exposed as a REST service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use Talend ESB for this kind of usage.
There is a very good tutorial on the Talend Website, for exposing REST service with a query in mysql database :
[How to create a REST Service](http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=English&idTuto=104)

More tutorials on Talend ESB can be found [here](http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/menu.php).