# Expose job as Web Service Talend

Tags: rest, web-services, talend

I have got a Talend job that as a finish product prepares zip package, now i want to expose this job as a REST server with GET request, so each time clients calls service the package is made and available to download. I know that there is a thread with exact same name [expose job as web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749634/expose-talend-etl-job-as-a-web-service) but accepted answer has links that are no longer valid.

Currently my job looks like this [image: designer view] [image: tJavaRow code][image: tMap view][image: tRestResponse View]

And the idea standing behind this design is that i got one column in output flow in tRESTRequest named "userfile" of type byte array, calling GET request tJavaRow starts and wrap file into byte array, then i transfer it through tMap to tRestRespone body as byte array. What am I missing?

Comment: You can use Talend ESB, here's a tutorial to help you: https://help.talend.com/reader/gOnPFFhbXGbCD5Ps7ez0iw/qOqJ9f0Zb8lVcz83MeB8TA

Comment: There is only shown an example of how to transfer simple xml document, what i need is how to transfer whole compressed folder.